# Biblatex supercite command with use of square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, superscripts

I want to use the package biblatex and cite with supercite but my problem is that if i use supercite the citations are not in square brackets anymore. Is it possible to get something like number-comp supercite and in square brackets?

In addition, i don't have much notion of that package and i am using LyX.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Related. Do you know which style `biblatex` is using? [Supercite with square brackets](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/287151) If not, the following is probably a duplicate, apart from the fact that you are using LyX. [Biblatex supercite with square brackets and grouped](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/114987)

Comment: thx @AlanMunn Supercite with square brackets works for me. I used the command style=chem-angew

Comment: Ok great, I'll mark it as a duplicate. If you also mark it the question will be closed immediately but not deleted, which is helpful for others.